# How to disable button depending on blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. How do I enable/disable a button depending on whether a cell is empty or not.

In excel sheet named "Sheet1" I have 1 button called "CommandButton1" assigned to a macro named "If_empty".

What I need to do is if column "F2" is empty I want to disable the button but if column "F2" has any values in it for the button to be enabled.

How do I achieve this?

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You could try adding a small reference sub that If (Cells(2, 6).Value = "" then Exit Sub Else Run_Normal_Macro
You could add a similar thing to the start of your existing code. It wont disable the button but clicking it will not apparently do anything.

Comment: I guess something like `CommandButton1.Enabled = [F2] > ""`

Comment: Slai, that's a good idea. I was thinking button on the worksheet not in a userform. 
If an worksheet activex control maybe set the event controls in the worksheet like this?
Private Sub CommandButton1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  If Cells(2, 6).Value = "" Then Exit Sub
  Call Macro
End Sub

Comment: Do like@Slai suggested and check it in a `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

As @Slai and Doug suggested, use the code below (add it to your `Worksheet_Change` event).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range
Dim i, j                        As Integer

Set WatchRange = Range("F2")

Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)
If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "" Then
        CommandButton1.Enabled = False
    Else
        CommandButton1.Enabled = True
    End If

End If

End Sub
```